# Trying to use input and def function in a program

Tags: python

I want to print out the user's given Fibonacci number but I am having trouble getting the input and def function to work together:

This is my code:

```
def fib(x):
    a = 0
    b = 1

   
    if x == 1:
        print(a)
         
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        
        for i in range(2,x):  
         c = a + b
         a = b
         b = c
         print(c)

x = input("What fibonacci factor would you like: ")

Result = fib(x)

print("Your fibonacci number is: " + str(Result))
```

How do I solve it, it brings back a type error for the "str" but I'm having trouble trying to fix it.

Comment: cast your input to integer ; x = int(input(....))

Comment: Your function also has no `return` statement, so it will only return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

First, your function does not return anything. Thus, the `Result` will always be `None`. If you want to get the result you need a `return` statement.

Second, the user input is of format `string`, therefore you get the error. Just define the type of `x`- either in the input field as suggested by @Ashkan or when calling your function `fib(int(x))`.

Third, by definition the `range()` function will stop before reaching `x` thus you have to increase this limit by `1`.

```
def fib(x):
    a = 0
    b = 1

   
    if x == 1:
        print(a)
         
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        
    for i in range(2,x+1):  
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(c)
    return c


x = input("What fibonacci factor would you like: ")

Result = fib(int(x))

print("Your fibonacci number is: " + str(Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

When receiving a input, the type is specified as a string.
You need to convert it to int.

Try:

```py
def fib(x):
    a = 0
    b = 1

   
    if x == 1:
        print(a)
         
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        
        for i in range(2,x):  
         c = a + b
         a = b
         b = c
         print(c)

x = input("What fibonacci factor would you like: ")

Result = fib(int(x))

print("Your fibonacci number is: " + str(Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out that while you are storing input from users, you are not converting it to int, that's why the problem was arising, also in your function you are not returning anything, that's why result holds None.
I fixed your code check out if it helps.

```
def fib(x):
    a = 0
    b = 1

   
    if x == 1:
        print(a)
         
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        
        for i in range(2,x):  
         c = a + b
         a = b
         b = c
         print(c)
    
    return x

x = int(input("What fibonacci factor would you like: "))

Result = fib(x)

print("Your fibonacci number is: " + str(Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want to output N (user input) Fibonacci numbers.

The built-in *input()* function returns a string. If you want to do any kind of arithmetic on an input value you'll need to convert it to an appropriate type - in this case *int*.

You should also consider changing your *fib()* function to generate the values and then print those values in the main program. This makes *fib()* reusable as something that merely generates the numbers but doesn't necessarily output them.

Something like this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

n = int(input('How many Fibonacci numbers would you like? : '))

for f in fibonacci(n):
    print(f)
```